# Form submission using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using  jQuery+JSON combination something like this:

test.php:

```
<form action='_test.php' method='post' class='ajaxform'>
 <input type='text' name='txt' value='Test Text'>
 <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<div id='testDiv'></div>
```

_test.php:

```
<?php
      // Code here to deal with your form submitted data.
      $arr = array( 'testDiv' => 'Form is successfully submitted.' );
      echo json_encode( $arr );
?>
```

jsFile.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.ajaxform').submit( function() {

        $.ajax({
            url     : $(this).attr('action'),
            type    : $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $(this).serialize(),
            success : function( data ) {
                        for(var id in data) {
                            jQuery('#' + id).html( data[id] );
                        }
                      }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

Now what i want is that when a successful form is submitted then without any page refresh a message should be displayed under the div testDiv. I was hoping that this script would help but when a form is submitted then the page goes to .../_test.php and displays the following -

```
{"testDiv":"Form is successfully submitted."}
```

Please help.Thanks in advanvce

Comment: You have a error in your JavaScript code. Open firebug and click "brake on all errors" to see what that error is. Fix it and you should be good to go.

Comment: Your page has `_test.php` but your description says `sms.php`...which is it? :)

Comment: I don't know jquery; but I don't observe anywhere that you are cancelling the (default) submit action, so I would guess that it does your submit function and then goes on and does a normal submit.

Comment: @Colin - There's a `return false` in the `.submit()` handler.

Comment: Ah. Missed that. I always explicitly cancel the event (with Event.stop() in prototype.js) so I forgot about the 'false' return.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just me or does this script work for anyone else? I have the three files as detailed above with the addition of the normal doctype and jquery core in the head in the test.php file and I get the success message without any page redirection.

Comment: go to http://174.132.194.155/~kunal17/devbuzzr/deals/5-discount-on-all-guitars and click on "grab coupon". then enter a number like 919262005226...see what happens..

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have got it or at least I got the same symptoms.

You need to check and make sure you load your jquery file in the script tag before `jsFile.js` script tag.

**BAD**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsFile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_api/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action='_test.php' method='post' class='ajaxform'>
    <label>
        <input type='text' name='txt' value='Test Text'>
    </label>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<div id='testDiv'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

**GOOD**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_api/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form action='_test.php' method='post' class='ajaxform'>
    <label>
        <input type='text' name='txt' value='Test Text'>
    </label>
    <input type='submit' value='submit'>
</form>

<div id='testDiv'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your JSON string is a bit wrong, you would need it to return:

`{"id":"testDiv","message":"Form is successfully submitted."}`

Then in the response:

```
for(var id in data) {
   jQuery('#' + data.id).html( data.message );
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct, what he has works, he's looping through the property/value pairs.  Even if it was incorrect, it wouldn't cause the behavior in the question.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just have normal button with a click event instead of a submit button?